# Use of varargin in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to use `varargin` in octave but seems that it is getting some problem. Here is my code:

**`into2.m`**

```
function  [result] = into2(x)
    result = x*2;
endfunction
```

**`into3.m`**

```
function  [result] = into3(x)
    result = x*3;
endfunction
```

**`calc.m`**

```
function  [result1] = calc(varargin, x)
    fn1 = varargin{1};
    fn2 = varargin{2};
    result1 = fn1(x) + fn2(x);
endfunction
```

**`test1.m`** (main function)

```
function  [] = test1()
    result= calc(@into2,@into3,2);
    disp(result);
endfunction
```

`test1()` is main function calling `calc()` and passing two function handles and one scalar. I expect that `varargin` should have `@into2,@into3` and `x` should have `2`. However, `varargin` has `@into2` and x has `@into3`. I tried changing order but two functions passed do not go into one argument; each argument has only one function. I believe that `varargin` should have a cell, but seems not working. I am using Octave 4.2. (Putting MATLAB into tag because the two should be similar.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `varargin` *must* appear as the *last* input argument to a function. If it is not the last, then it is simply treated as an input parameter *named* `varargin` instead. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Variable_002dlength-Argument-Lists.html):

> If the special parameter name `varargin` appears **at the end of a function parameter list** it indicates that the function takes a variable number of input arguments

So in effect, your `calc` function is functionally no different from:

```
function result = calc(y, x)
```

What you'll want to do instead, is place `varargin` last in the list of input arguments and modify the logic within `calc`.

```
function result = calc(x, varargin)
    fn1 = varargin{1};
    fn2 = varargin{2};

    result = fn1(x) + fn2(x);
end
```

As a side note, it's not clear why exactly you need to use `varargin` in this scenario since you don't actually have a variable number of inputs.